# Ubuntu server with many partitions

Tags: files, mount, nginx

I have this problem with my VPS running ubuntu.

```
/dev/nbd0 46G 46G 0 100% / 
/dev/nbd1 46G 52M 44G 1% /mnt/data
```

Now, since `nbd0` is already full, how do I start using `nbd1`. All my website files are under `/var/www/mydomain1`.

Do I need to create a similar folder under `/mnt/data` like `/mnt/data/var/www/mydomain1`?

I'm not sure how to achieve this because using SFTP to upload website files and I'm uploading all my files inside `/var/www/mydomain1`. Now, my issue is all the wordpress files are inside `/var/www/mydomain1` and wordpress files are inside `nbd0` volume. If I start uploading files inside `/mnt/data`, how am I supposed to make this work. I am using Wordpress.

Comment: Considering it unlikely that your WordPress installation would take more than a GB, shouldn't you instead look into moving something else (bigger) to the new partition?  Doing so would save you the complications that triggered this question.

Comment: The website allows users to upload large files and documents.

Comment: It's easy to use both partitions but not in the same folder.  This is what complicates your situation with WordPress which stores everything in the same place.  You will need to look at the `wp-contents` folder to figure out how you can organize the move to split the contents in two.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by split the contents in two. So do i have to maintain the wp-contents in both partition? Is there any similar setup that i can refer with some modifications ofcourse. Its been two days now looking everywhere, i don't even know where to begin. Is this where i have to use symlinks.

Comment: It all depends on how things are organized and what takes a lot of space in your WordPress installation.  As I suggested previously, it would probably be much simpler to move something else than parts of your WordPress installation to the new partition.  You merely replied the possible presence of big files on your site.  You will need to much better clarify what is taking how much space and how you wish to deal with it.  This can not be determined by some random stranger that has no clue of your installation.

Comment: Ok, so wp-contents is the folder thats eating up space. These two folders thats used all the time --> wp-contents/uploads and wp-contents/cache .

Comment: You could possibly just move the `cache` folder to the new partition and soft-link to it.  Then test it and if it causes an error, there are a few settings which may need to be touched depending on what error it gives you.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, let me try now on a new server.

Answer (score 0):

Move one large directory tree to `/mnt/data` and create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to it in the root partition. The actual location under `/mnt/data` doesn't matter: nothing connects `/SOME/PATH` to `/mnt/data/SOME/PATH` a priori.

```
service nginx stop
mv /var/www /mnt/data
ln -s /mnt/data/www /var
service nginx start
```

Don't put the symbolic link under the web root: most web servers are configured not to follow symbolic links, to limit the effect of path traversal attacks.

Comment: Ok, i'll try this on a new server now. Another confusing thing is what happens if /dev/nbd1 is full and i have to add another /dev/nbd2 . Do i need to follow the same procedure? Thank you so much for the guide you have given.

Comment: @Allroundstart:  If you think this is a possibility, you should consider making a volume group instead of dealing with separate partitions.